# does ListView re-draws itself every time the adapter changed?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to make a list of SMSs in my own application..

my question is about the steps makes by the adapter (automatic)

-when new message arrived I adds it to list object (not the ListView).
-then I passes the list to the adapter of the listView.
**the adapter GetView() method run for every Item in the list**

-I notify the listview about the change.
- the listview **re-draws all**  its existing rows and then draw the new row.

### My question: this behavior (re-draw and redraw, it mean every row will be drown times equal to the total rows) affect the performance?

**if the question is not clear I say: does the ListView Draw all the Raws just to add new  row? **

Comment: You may need to call notifyDataSetChanged(); in the getView-method to update the view

Comment: My question is : does the ListView draw all the rows to add new row???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ListView doesn't redraw every single item in order to add one. It will only be drawn when you scroll to it. And yes you have to notify ListView that the change had happened.

Comment: After you call notifyDataSetChanged() it will draw only the items that are visible on the screen also it reuses views that are created by getView() for optimization.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to add the item at the top position. So all other item's position and index will change . Adapter will redraw the whole list(only elements which are visible on the screen) .

For performance you can use viewHolder pattern.
see this link 
[Making ListView Scrolling Smooth][1]http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: If you change in data set and you call notifyDataSetChanged(). then items which are visible to screen will be redraw And as i said you can use viewholder to optimize it.